# How do I make selenium find an element whos Id changes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am automating with selenium and running into an issue where everytime I refresh a page, the element ID changes, no matter if I copy XPATH, CSS Selector, ID, they all have a number in them that changes.

so the code I'm using is simple, I just want to click the button which I can accomplish with

```
browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='*VALUE HERE*').click()
```

But I don't know what to put as the value.
Here is the HTLM code

```
<a class="x4-tab x4-unselectable x4-box-item x4-tab-default x4-noicon x4-tab-noicon x4-tab-default-noicon x4-top x4-tab-top x4-tab-default-top x4-tab-after-title x4-active x4-tab-active x4-tab-default-active x4-top-active x4-tab-top-active x4-tab-default-top-active" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" id="tab-1965" tabindex="0" data-ui-comp-name="wm-np-tab-wrkstn" style="right: auto; left: 66px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;">
<span id="tab-1965-btnWrap" role="presentation" class="x4-tab-wrap" unselectable="on">
  <span id="tab-1965-btnEl" class="x4-tab-button" role="presentation">
    <span id="tab-1965-btnInnerEl" class="x4-tab-inner x4-tab-inner-center" 
    unselectable="on">Workstations</span>
    <span role="presentation" id="tab-1965-btnIconEl" class="x4-tab-icon-el  " unselectable="on" 
    style="">
  </span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

If you look at the HTML, anywhere you see that number 1965, that number will change if the page is refreshed. How do I make selenium find this element no matter what that number is?

Also, not sure if this matters but this is all in an iframe which I have selenium target by using

```
frame1 = browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='defaultView')

browser.switch_to.frame(frame1)
```

Also, another problem is that HTML code is almost identical to other buttons, the only differences between the buttons is that number (that changes) and where is says "Workstations". Here is an example of another button that is next to it, this one is for servers.

```
<span id="tab-1964-btnWrap" role="presentation" class="x4-tab-wrap" unselectable="on">
  <span id="tab-1964-btnEl" class="x4-tab-button" role="presentation">
    <span id="tab-1964-btnInnerEl" class="x4-tab-inner x4-tab-inner-center" 
    unselectable="on">Servers</span>
    <span role="presentation" id="tab-1964-btnIconEl" class="x4-tab-icon-el" 
    unselectable="on" style="">
  </span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XPath for this:

```
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[starts-with(@id, 'tab-') and contains(@id, '-btnEl')]").click()
```

Comment: It is an example to find an element with id = tab-\*-btnEl\*

Comment: there are multiple other buttons though in the code, wouldn't this clash with the other buttons that have similar names?

Comment: you can combine different attributes of your elements. for example //span[starts-with(@id, 'tab-') and contains(@id, 'btnInnerEl') and contains(@class, 'x4-tab-inner') and contains(text(), 'Workstations')]

Comment: It is up to you what to use as unique set of attributes to locate one particular element. If you can be sure that text inside element will be unique among other ones then you can use //span[text()="Servers"] and //span[text()="Workstations"]

Comment: I tried
`browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//span[text()="Workstations"]').click()`
but that didnt work. Said unable to locate element

Comment: Can you try //span[contains(text(), "Workstations")] ?

Comment: still same thing, cannot find element, although if I type //span[text()="Workstations"] into the inspect element search, it will return with 1 found and it is the button I need to click. So I do not know why selenium cannot see it

Comment: I'm an idiot. I put my switch to frame command in a function and didnt realize I deleted the function so it wasn't focusing on the iframe. I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh. Can you print(browser.page_source) ?

Comment: Got it! You are welcome :)